# Whitelisting Objects

Tags: apex, singleemailmessage

I'm in the process of writing a method that will send e-mails through Salesforce using E-mail templates. However, I'm getting the following error:

[image]

> System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, Onl accounts, assets, campaigns, cases, opportunities, orders, productions, solutions and custom objects are allowed asWhatId.: [whatId, 003D000001tsKtd]

I'm currently iterating over `sObject` and obviously are setting a Contact Id as WhatId. Now I know I can simply do something like:

```
if (!(obj instanceOf Contact)) {
  message.setWhatId((String)obj.get('Id'));
}
```

But what if something else gets passed in, like a Lead?

I figured the best thing to do would be to White List objects rather than include ones that'll cause problems. After all, I know I can only use Accounts, Assets, Campaigns etc...

Whilst I know I can do something like:

```
if ((obj instanceOf Account) || (obj instanceOf Asset) || (obj instanceOf Campaign)[...]) {
  message.setWhatId((String)obj.get('Id'));
}
```

But then I was wondering, is there a better way? Also, how could I do something like `(obj instanceOf Custom)`? Does that exist?

Can I do something like (granted this will be wrong):

```
Set<sObject> whiteList = new Set<sObject>{
  Account,
  Asset,
  Campaign
};

if (whiteList.get(obj)) {
  // Do something...
}
```

I guess I'm looking for the best, most future-proof way of handling this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WhatId can be anything *except* Contact or Lead, so it'd be far more reasonable to simply check for that instead:

```
if(record.Id.getSobjectType() == Lead.SObjectType || record.Id.getSObjectType() == Contact.SObjectType) {
    message.setWhoId(record.Id);
} else {
    message.setWhatId(record.Id);
}
```

You can also describe the object to see if it's custom:

```
if(record.Id.getSobjectType().getDescribe().isCustom()) {
    record.setWhatId(record.Id);
}
```

Of course, this won't cover all possible scenarios; it's possible that the object in question doesn't support tasks, in which case, this method may still fail, so I'm pretty sure you'll need a try-catch block anyways (but this should only occur in test/sandbox code/environments).

Comment: I guess it'd be more efficient to just exclude Contact and Lead objects and catch errors if a record doesn't, as you say, support Tasks. Thanks for this.